# Rename dicom images

Tags: matlab, rename, dicom

I have 110 CT dicom images, and their names are randoms, so when I display them using any dicom viewer, they are displayed randomly. Thus I am trying to rename these dicom images according to their Image Number (0020,0013) or Slice Location (0020,1041). I have already started to write a script

```
image_list=dir('*.dcm');
 for i=1:25
    img=dicomread(image_list(i).name);
    imgHdr = dicominfo(image_list(i).name);
 dicomwrite(img, ['T' num2str(i) '.dcm'], imgHdr,'CreateMode','Copy')
end
```

But I don't know how to tell it check the InstanceNumber and use it in the new name ?

Comment: I used a `.dcm` provided by MatLab (`info = dicominfo('CT-MONO2-16-ankle.dcm')` and I did not find `Image Number` within the info provided by `dicominfo`. What do you mean with `check the image number `?

Comment: @il_raffa Sorry, I meant InstanceNumber in Matlab (Image Number in imageJ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `InstanceNumber` is accessible as an element of the `dicominfo` output struct:

```
instancenumber = ImgHdr.InstanceNumber;
```

And I would construct the filename using `sprintf`

```
outputfilename = sprintf('T%04d', instancenumber);
```

There are many formats for `sprintf` mirroring those from C++'s `printf`, The ones I used above print an integer (the 'd') with 4 digits (the '4'), zero padded (the '0'). This is good for automatic sorting by file managers. If you need a different format check the docs [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to add the following line to your script:

```
imgHdr.InstanceNumber = i;
```

and try to load the images in a viewer.

Comment: Thanks vizhanyolajos for your reply, I tried it but they are displayed randomly again.

Comment: I'll try something for you tomorrow ... if I'll have time for it.

Comment: Thanks vizhanyolajos, I managed to do it as xenoclast suggested. Thanks again for your helps